# Entity Framework Fluent many-to-many configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluentvalidation

I have these tables:

**Item**
Id (PK)
CategoryA
CategoryB
CategoryC

**Category**
Category (PK)
CategoryType (PK)
Market (PK)
Name

On the Item table I want 3 navigational properties:
CategoriesA: uses CategoryA which maps to Category table with CategoryId and CategoryType = 1
CategoriesB: uses CategoryB which maps to Category table with CategoryId and CategoryType = 2
CategoriesC: uses CategoryC which maps to Category table with CategoryId and CategoryType = 3
Notice Market is not used which doesn't exist on Item.

And of course vice versa meaning a row in Category should be able to navigate to it's items using this property:
Items: uses Category which maps to Item table with CategoryA if Category's CategoryType is 1, CategoryB if CategoryType is 2 and CategoryC if CategoryType is 3.

I don't understand these more complex navigational configurations.

I have been reading on here but I can't get my grasp around builder.HasMany(...).WithMany(...).**UsingEntity**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use derived types for category

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryA : Category
{

}

public class CategoryB : Category
{

}

public class CategoryC : Category
{

}
```